# Datatype for time notification in android

Tags: android, time, types, notifications

I am creating an app in which a `notification` of time should be shown, like `15 secs ago / 2 mins ago / 1 hour ago / 2 hrs 15 mins ago`, the kind like which they show on `whatsapp`, messenger etc., What kind of datatype should I use for this? I am passing it as String, like this `"time.setText(String.valueOf(m.getTime()));"`
 Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long, long, long, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long,%20int)). For example:

```
CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            Long.parseLong(m.getTime() or yourTimeValue),
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
yourTimeTextView.setText(timeAgo);
```

which return (quote from official document)

> Returns a string describing 'time' as a time relative to 'now'.
>
> Time spans in the past are formatted like "42 minutes ago". Time spans in the future are formatted like "in 42 minutes".

Comment: Thanks for your time zzas11..
I'm actually passing this, "time.setText(String.valueOf(m.getTime()));" in Adapter class. How to pass it as you said? Sorry if my question looks stupid.. I am actually new to android as well as programming

Comment: what is your m.getTime()? and can use the code in your Adapter class. Replace yourTimeTextView.setText(timeAgo); to time.setText(timeAgo);

Comment: "m"  is to get necessary data to the row. Like this:


 // getting notifications data for the row
 Users m = notifications.get(position);

Comment: so getTime() will return String of time? for example 1437030647 which is current timestamp.

Comment: I am actually doing my app with the help of this link.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

If u go through the customlistadapter.java in that link, you could understand my situation. I am trying to show "time" in the place of "year" instead of year.

Comment: yes you are right. To return time and populate it in the list actually

Comment: then you can add the suggested code above `time.setText(String.valueOf(m.getTime()));` and change to `time.setText(timeAgo);`.  Modify  `Long.parseLong(m.getTime() or yourTimeValue)` to `Long.parseLong(m.getTime())`

Comment: CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(m.getTime()), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                time.setText(timeAgo);


Is this correct?

Comment: Yes and this will show the format that you want to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot zzas11. Its working perfect with nil errors. I'll let you know, when I check my output.

Comment: Hey zzas11, somethings changed in my code. I'm now doing it like this:
`textView2.setText(notifications.get(position).getString("notified_on"));`
When i do this it shows, the date and time. When I change the code with DateUtils like this:

`CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong("notified_on"),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        textView2.setText(timeAgo);`

it shows nothing. Is my code right?

Comment: Add notification.get(position).getString("notified_on") into Long.parseLong().

Comment: It doesn't help either. I added as you said.

`CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                        Long.parseLong(notifications.get(position).getString("notified_on")),
                        System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                textView2.setText(timeAgo);`

Comment: Convert notification.get(position).getString("notified_on") to unix timestamp and pass into Long.parseLong()

Comment: any tutorials for this kind zzas11? I've never done this before. Also, i use a php server

Comment: You can learn from androidhive.com and for your question, this tutorial should be perfect for you. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/